# How to snap two solid cylinders together

Tags: snapping

[image]I want to join two solid cylinders ('rods') together (end to end) without the need to move one using Grab via trial and error. I tried using Snapping>Vertex also Edge and Face without success. I looked at two similar questions which didn't work for me.
What is the easiest or correct method to do this?
What I am doing this for is to apply different materials to each end so maybe there also is another method to create two different objects from a single cylinder?

Comment: could you please show some screenshots? You could bridge the two ends for example...

Comment: Select the top cylinder.
Enable vertex snapping to closest.
Press 'G' to move, Then 'Z' to move only on Z-axis.
While holding 'CTRL' move your object and aim for one of the top vertexes to snap to it.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is just two materials, you could use a single cylinder, add a loop cut in the middle, and assign a new material slot to the top half.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That is probably faster than duplicating and then snapping.BUT how do I make the 'cut' stick ie create two objects as after I made the cut I still only had a single (cylinder) object (when I went to object mode there was only one cylinder).

Comment: The loop cut only creates vertices around the outside.  It doesn't split the mesh in half or create internal faces.  You could always use the Rip tool and create some faces, but at that point if you want two meshes you should just start with two meshes.  This is two materials sharing one mesh. :)

Comment: Thanks Allen. All I was trying to create is a POLE (cylinder) with two different image textures applied one to the top and one to the bottom (not solid colors).

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out.
I selected one cylinder then used Snap to> Increment with Absolute Grid Snap selected, moved the cylinder then selected the other cylinder and did the same and it snapped to the first cylinder.

Comment: Take into account that this will only work when your object's dimensions are equal or in a power of the abszolute grid size.